# BigQuery is there any way to break the large result into smaller chucks for processing?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi i am new to the BigQuery, if i need to fetch a very large set of data, say more than 1 GB, how can i break it into smaller pieces for quicker processing? i will need to process the result and dump it into a file or elasticsearch. i need to find a efficient way to handle it. i tried with the QueryRequest.setPageSize option, but that does't seem to work. I set 100 and it doesn't seem to break on every 100 record i put this line to see how many record i get back before i turn to a new page

```
result = result.getNextPage();
```

it displays at random number of records. sometimes at 1000, sometimes at 400, etc.
thanks

Comment: BigQuery works best not as a store of large data volumes for processing elsewhere, but as the place where you do the processing. Importing and exporting is expensive compared to querying/processing. Why not adapt your case to do what BigQuery is good at?

Comment: You could open issue here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues 
and link back to the stack overflow question, that way it doesn't get lost.

Comment: i was given to pull data from bigquery. so i had no choice but to find a solution. i did find something at stackoverflow to use the bigquery api to get query result. the api returns reuslts in pages. each page contains by default about 100k records. so i was able to pull the data fairly quick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you but in our project we have something that seems to be similar: we process lots of data in BigQuery and need to use the final result for later usage (it contains roughly 15 Gbs for us when compressed).

What we did was to first save the results to a table with `AllowLargeResults` set to `True` and then export the result by compressing it into cloud storage using the [Python API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.extract_table_to_storage).

It automatically breaks the results into several files.

After that we have a Python script that downloads concurrently all files, reads through the whole thing and builds some matrices for us.

I don't quite remember how long it takes to download all the files, I think it's around 10 minutes. I'll try to confirm this one.